# call the username that select item for current user login

Tags: php, html, yii2

I have a system that user can login, and can select the event and will save into the database.

However, the problem is that i can set to only one user, as you can see in line 9 in the save.php

So my question is, how to set the user in the system to be automatic so that if other user login, the data will be save under their name. the problem is because the login is using yii2 framework and this select event is using html and the model of the event is using gii,

Here are my code:

The code for viewevents.php

```
    <?php

    echo '<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>';

    $event = get_events();
    function get_events(){
        include ("../config/connect.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `events` order by event_id desc;";
        if ($result = $dayahlatiff->query($sql)) { $in = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $new_res[$in] = $row;
             $in++;
        }
        $result->free();
    }

        return isset($new_res)?$new_res:array();
    }

    $this->title = 'View Events';
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
    ?>

    <?php $in = 1;
     if (!empty($event)) {
        include 'events.php';
    }
    ?>
```

The code for save.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset( $_SESSION["id_"])){
    //    $hh = $_SESSION["id_"];
   //    die($hh);
    }
    require("../../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php");
    $user = "dayahlatiff";
  //$user = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
    /* 
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project  Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    if(isset($_POST["save"])){
        include ("../../config/connect.php");
        $where = $_POST["where"];
        $list = $_POST["check_list"];
        if(empty($list)){
            header("Location: ".$where);
        }else {
            $done = true;
            for($s = 0; $s<sizeof($list); $s++){
                $event = $list[$s];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `selectevents` (`user_id`, `username`,  `event_title`) VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$event');";
                 if($dayahlatiff->query($sql) === FALSE){
                     $event = false;
                 }
            }
          header("Location: ".$where);
       }
  }
```

Comment: This looks like some old legacy PHP code forced to use Yii. Why are you not using Yii 2 properly?

Comment: @Bizley actually, i've tried using yii2, but it's not working..so i get help from my friend, but he is not too master using yii2, that's why the code is mixing yii2 and html. however, the html code is only for this 2 file (viewevents.php and save.php)

Comment: The commented line with `//$user = ...` is exactly the way to get the username of logged Yii 2 user but I really doubt if you can use it like that here without any problems. Besides your code is open to SQL injection. Yii 2 is not that difficult to learn. Check the [Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) and do it properly.

Comment: replace code  (NULL, '$user', '$event') to  (NULL, '.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.', '.$event.')

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you getting some information about

- Object Oriented Programming
- MVC structure
- Namespacing
- Active Record

And getting a little bit familier with yii2 and its documentation.

This code is pure PHP, in frameworks such as Yii2, there is no such things as including files or connecting to databases like that.

Take a close look at Yii2 documentation from [This Url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) and try to code using the concepts available under Yii2 structure. Make sure you get familier with this concepts and try to forget old school native PHP programming.